# Styling superscript element within HTML select option

Tags: html, css, mobile, interface

I need to include a superscript registered trademark symbol inside an HTML `<option>` tag. In a perfect world, I would use the following markup:

```
<select> 
   <option> My Product <sup>&reg;</sup> </option>
</select>
```

However, I am designing for the iPhone Safari and Android native browsers, which ignore the `<sup>` and interpret the text within the `<option>` as plaintext.

My question has two parts:

1. Is there a CSS "hack" that will allow me to override the native functionality of these two mobile browsers?
2. If a simple hack does not exist, what would be the simplest and most efficient alternative?

Additional considerations that may or may not factor into the answer:

1. I'm developing exclusively for iPhone and Android web browsers.
2. Performance is very important. For this reason, I'm using Zepto.js and would prefer to stay away from jQuery and jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to make a `&reg; ®` superscript inside an `<option> tag`. You're stuck with a regular ® `&reg;`

you can use some superscript `alphabets` `numbers` etc. in `<option>` tag looks like below code

```
<select>
    <option>24&#x1D57;&#x02B0;</option>
</select>
```

It's `answer` is
        24ᵗʰ
    . In Unicode `MODIFIER LETTER SMALL t` is `&#x1D57;` and `MODIFIER LETTER SMALL h` is `&#x02B0;`

for complete unicode list visit this site http://www.uni-graz.at/~vollmanr/unicode/

Comment: Hi Khizer, thanks for taking the time to offer feedback. While I appreciate your suggestion, the issue I'm having is that the two browsers' default behavior is to ignore CSS styles within the <option> tag. So, no matter how I tweak the CSS, the browser will not pay attention to it.